# How do I implement something after a series of button clicks in a certain order and within a certain time period in Android studio if I had 2 buttons

Tags: java, android, android-studio

If I had 2 buttons in the android studio and if I wanted to implement something when the 2 buttons are pressed in a certain order and within a certain time period, how would the code be like?
Supposing 2 buttons, button1 and button2 and if pressed in the order button1, button2, button2, button1 implements some activty.
button1.onClick ----(within 1 second)---> button2.onClick ----(within 1 second)---> button2.onClick ----(within 1 second)---> button1.onClick -----> Then do some activity.
I hope this explains what I'm trying to achieve.
Any help is much appreciated. :)

UPDATE
This is what I have so far but I am nowhere close to even sure if this is the right way to go about this

I put an on click listener for both

```
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  if(view == buttonOne) {
    //a timer for 1 second {
      if(view == buttonTwo) {
        //a timer for 1 second {
          if(view == buttonTwo) {
            //a timer for 1 second {
              if(view == buttonOne) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Some.class));
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand the question!

Comment: @Xenolion Okay supposing there are 2 buttons on screen. There is a pre-defined order that if i click the first button, then the 2nd button twice and the first button again within a maximum interval of 1 second between each button click, it opens a certain activity or does a certain function. Does that make the question any more understandable? Sorry if it didn't, but i'm trying to make it clear.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @0X0nosugar I have no clue how to go about it :/

Comment: Start with an Activity with two Buttons. (Please understand, we're not here to write code for you, only to help you with your code. So please show us what you've got so far.)

Comment: I have understood it now! You are supposed to prepare a logic to handle that the way you wish! Prepare some variable and setting them different plus adding a timer that will reset values if a certain time is above 1 second!

Comment: @Xenolion That is what im trying to do. The timer part i can do, but i dont know the correct way to code for nested button calls.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Sorry for not doing that earlier. But i've done so now. Any help?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to see :)

Comment: @0X0nosugar Sorry sir, I'm new to the forum.

Comment: @PaulJose I would like to know how much of a logic or pattern of button clicks you want? And dont worry about stackOveflow rules. You will get used to them. Users will direct new users!

Comment: @Xenolion Haha thanks. I wanted to implement it like the one i mentioned, button1 click, then button2 click, then button2 click, then button1 click. Is this what you asked for?

Comment: So you only have two button but want to check for 4 clicks right?

Comment: @Xenolion Yes thats what i wanted to do

Comment: Okay Iet me check a best design to check it, Working on it! Though I do not have an IDE here but If you find any syntax error let me now so I can edit the answer !

Comment: @Xenolion Okay will do. Its 3 AM here, and i'm really tired, I will try your code tomorrow. Thank you for the help anyway.

Comment: Okay worry out you will find it when you wake up! Its 23:00 here!

Comment: @Xenolion Thank you sir. Sorry for keeping you up.

Comment: Is the answer given by another user solve your question? @PaulJose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution works by using handlers and delaying doing something for some time for this case 1 second. Because all the buttons have integer ids then the solution will work to prepare for you an integer array for ids in the right order you can later on loop in an array checking the ids in it comparing it with id of your buttons. Initially all button ids are zero (`0`), And if they user clicks the button he will be adding the right integer id if he doesnt click any other button in a period of 1 second. All ids in the array will be zero (`0`) again, except only if the last click is the 4th click and after that you will have to handle your logic by checking the array yourself.

Lets start by declaring the variables we shall use (*Remember to read comments*):

```
private Handler handler; //handler to delay all work in 1 second
private Runnable runnable; //runnable this will be doing the job in another thread
private int[] buttonIDs = {0, 0, 0, 0}; //all button ids are zero initially
private int pressNumber=-1; //The user has not clicked anything
```

These are two methods you will have to add in your class.

The first method:

```
private void startCounter() {

    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(buttonIDs[3]==0){ // if the last id is still zero lets clear everything and start afresh
             clearEverything();
          }                       
    }
 }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000); // we tell it dont execute the code in run until a 1000 milliseconds which is 1 second
}
```

And the second method is:

```
private void clearEverything(){
     // clear everything will really start everything afresh always call this method first if you want to repeat the game start afresh
     pressNumber=-1;
     for(int i=0;i < 4;i++) {
        buttonIDs[i] = 0;
     }
}
```

The code inside onClick finally is simply this:

```
if(pressNumber < 3){
   pressNumber++; //increment the pressing to another value
   buttonIDs[pressNumber] = view.getId(); //use that value as index to button id
   if(runnable != null){
          handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); // if there was any handler still running cancel it first because we have clicked some button
   }
   startCounter(); //after click always start counter and remember if the counter finishes it will reset everything
} else{

 //Do something here the user has clicked all the buttons 4 times without delaying 1 second each!. The order of button clicks is the integer array buttonIDs and you can clearEverything(); to start again!

}
```